# Possible analytic evaluation of integral

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, substitution

I'm wondering if the following integral can be done analytically?

$$I(x) = \int_{x/4}^1 \text{d}y\,y^{3/2+a} \,\,(1-y)^{1/2}\,\, \exp \left(c\sqrt{\ln \left(\frac{4y}{x} \right)} \right),$$ where $a$ and $c$ are constants satisfying  $3/2+a>0$ and $c>0$ with $x \ll 1$ (if this helps).

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: In which context did you catch this monster ?

Comment: @EDX I’ve tried a few substitutions, part of the integrand looks like a beta function but there is also the y dependent exp factor. Was trying also to see if possible to remove all dimensionality from the integral (that is, so the function of x can be extracted multiplicatively and the integral is simply a number but I think this is not possible)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici it was physics :)

Comment: *"o you who enter here give up all hope"* as  Dante Alighieri wrote in the Divine Comedy ! Back to serious, as I wrote it, I am more than skeptical about a possible closed form.